# Reading CR terminated keyword text file

Tags: c, file-io, strstr

I want to read a list of keywords from a (text) file and then add those in a CString array in C. The trouble is that, I am reading the file line by line, and the file contains one word in every line. I can successfully populate the array, but when I try to look up these keywords in another string, it returns false because I am guessing the keyword has *\n* at the end.

Another way I could read the file could be, to make the text file a comma separated file, and read one line and tokenize it. But then, I won't know how to read a line whose size can be VERY large, as the list of keyword is ever expanding.

Saad Rehman

Comment: how do you read from file? provide some code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your problem is that a string may have a rogue newline at the end, you can use:

```
size_t len = strlen (mystring);
if (len > 0)
    if (mystring[len-1] == '\n')
        mystring[--len] = '\0';
```

Do this to `mystring` after you've read it in but before you use it.

It simply checks if the last character is a newline and, if so, replaces it with a string terminator.

The first check is to ensure you don't try this on an empty string where `mystring[-1]` would invoke the dreaded undefined behaviour.

Comment: If you're going to re-use `len`, it may be a good idea to update it when replacing the `'\n'` with a null terminator: eg `mystring[--len] = '\0';`.

Comment: Good point, @pmg, I don't usually do that but, since it wastes very little (both effort and source code), I've adopted your suggestion on the off chance that someone else may.

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm :)

Though I did try this before myself, and it wasn't working. I though LF and CR were represented by something other than _\n_ - but your code totally worked.